# Does firebase notification call 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:' after force close an iOS app?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:  method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background. But I want to send push notification after force an app to close on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. It is important update my apps data silently. I have already tried silent push notification in background mode. But it's not work in quite mode.

Will iOS perform background tasks after the user has force-quit the app?

If perform, fiarebase push notification build in method application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: execute?

Please reply anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, apps that were force-closed via the task manager are not normally restarted when push notifications are received. This is [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7):

> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the device before the app can be launched automatically into the background by the system. When password protection is enabled on the device, the system does not launch an app in the background before the user first unlocks the device